# How to define onDraw() in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, ondraw, onpaint

I understand that the `onDraw()` function is virtual void which is called automatically via `OnPaint()`, which is itself triggered by the WM_PAINT message.

My declaration goes something like this:

myDialog.cpp

```
void myDialog::OnDraw(CDC* dc)
{
    CCustomMemDC pDC(dc);
    CExampleDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
}
```

myDialog.h

`afx_msg void OnDraw(CDC* dc);`

and in my `OnPaint()`

`CDialog::OnPaint();`

However I could not get OnDraw to be triggered at all... Could anyone enlighten if this method is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: `OnPaint`/`OnDraw` is primarily (if not exclusively) for *views*. You don't normally want to mess with drawing directly in a dialog--you want to put controls in the dialog, and they should draw into their own areas, and let the rest of the dialog take care of itself.

Comment: My motivation for doing so, as I am following the tutorial to remove flicker on my screen. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33/Flicker-Free-Drawing-In-MFC

Answer (score 2):

A dialog has no OnDraw. This is a virtual function in views to allow printing and drawing to a screen.

In a dialog just use OnPaint. There isno redirection to a virtual OnDraw function in a dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct.  As others have pointed out, OnDraw() is a virtual method of CView and not CDialog.  Therefore, your OnDraw() method will never be called.

I don't know why your dialog would have a flicker problem that you would need to mitigate it.  If you have a custom control on the dialog that is causing flicker, then you probably need to fix the drawing code in it and possibly add WS_CLIPCHILDREN as a Window Style to your dialog.  That will make sure that the background of the custom control is not erased when the dialog executes its WM_ERASEBKGND message.

It makes no sense to override the WM_PAINT of the dialog unless you are really planning to do custom drawing on it.  Unless you have a very good reason, don't do it.

If you choose to ignore the advice then add an ON_WM_PAINT() to your message handler to the dialog, and then draw the dialog yourself:

```
void myDialog::OnPaint()
{
   CPaintDC dc(this);
   CCustomMemDC pDC(&dc);
   // do your specialized code knowing you are responsible for drawing the whole dialog
}
```

If you really want to use your OnDraw() method, then you could also write OnPaint() like this:

```
void myDialog::OnPaint()
{
   CPaintDC dc(this);
   OnDraw(&dc);
}
```

But, the first thing I would do in your situation is try adding the style `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` to your dialog style.